# Best place to write SQL queries

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, sql

I've been working on this project for my company. Currently I am embedding my SQL statements inside the program itself as and when they are needed. I do have two seperate classes -

1. QueryBuilder Class (Contains all the queries)
2. DbConnection Class (Executes the queries against the database, takes care of connectivity and such)

   What this does, is whenever I need to make the smallest adjustment in the query, I have to rebuild the entire application.

I'm hoping there are better ways to deal with this. Somewhere I can store these queries,  get them, pass the parameters **as command parameters**, then execute them and if I have to, change them without having to rebuild my application.

There are a couple of ideas in my head.

1. Resource files.
2. Seperate DLL/Class files - Disadvantage is that, I'll have to rebuild that class if I make a change to that code. But the seperation does have it's advantage.
3. Text files, May get unmanageable when queries increase.

I'd like to know if there is a better way to deal with this issue and if others have any way of circumventing this.

Comment: What is wrong with rebuilding the app after material changes?

Comment: hope your using a connection pool. we generally have sql inside the code. how often do you think you would need to change the sql and not the code? another way would be to call stored procedures for all SQL

Comment: You haven't even mentioned some of the most popular choices, like object-relational mapping, or a service-oriented architecture, or stored procedures, or LINQ... There's a lot of options out there, and this kind of architectural choice is worth a bit of deliberation.

Comment: I second the comment by @KilianFoth, you should have a think about Entity Framework and others... having hand-crafted SQL queries is generally viewed as a last resort these days, particularly on the Microsoft stack. Their entire strategy is built on top of EF, including their entire reporting stack.

Comment: @guysherman fair points but I'm not sure how right that is -- you are seeing alot of people using hand-crafted sql, such as the folks who built this site. If you are past simple crud operations it can work out really well and there is lots of depth to SQL that ORMs hide. Not that I have anything against ORMs.

Comment: @WyattBarnett you are right, ORMs can hide a great deal of depth - I guess my point is more that Microsoft are pushing EF as their preferred way of interacting with SQL Server from code. The entire semantic modelling layer of SSRS is implemented on top of it.

I vastly prefer to have all queries at my application layer, rather than as stored procedures, and I find it more readable to have these as LINQ-to-Entities queries than as SQL in my code, because they can remain close to the code that consumes the data, without peppering the code with large string literals.

Comment: @KilianFoth's comment it right-on.  The best place to write SQL queries would be "none of the above" given the options you have outlined.  If you insist on one of the approaches you have listed, please tell me that you will at least use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: I can't use EF or LINQ for this project. A lot of our projects still use good old SQL queries. And yes, I'm using parameterized queries.

Comment: When you say you 'cant' use EF or Linq.... why?

Comment: @Milney - This was three years ago. EF and LINQ skill sets were low in the company at that time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Resource files**, as well as a simple **App.config file** may do the work.

Having the queries in a **separate library** is a good way too, especially if you're using it as a plugin (and so you don't have to recompile the application itself, nor even restart it if it's currently running). Since the library contains only constants, compiling it would take at most a few milliseconds.

As for **text files**, I don't see any benefit, given that the drawback is that you have to reinvent the wheel, i.e. invent your own format, while resource files or App.config already provide that.

---

Note: be very, very careful. Changing queries is something that should be taken seriously, since it can radically change the behavior of the application (and, why not, wipe out the whole database or table because of a mistake like a forgotten `where` in a `delete from`). **I would highly recommend not only to recompile the application, but also to rerun the integration tests** (and unit tests, if there are unit tests which deal with the database directly).

Security is another concern. You have to **be sure that only authorized persons would be able to modify the queries**. For example, it would be a disaster to put SQL queries in a way that an ordinary user of a desktop application can modify them: users would imagine they are experts in SQL, modify the queries in a way that it will wipe out their database, and once a disaster occurs, they will blame your product instead of their own stupidity.

Comment: It's not so likely that users will wipe out the database with their modifications, but it *is* pretty likely that they will write monstrously inefficient queries that bring the entire server down under the load.

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait for a day for some more suggestions before selecting this as an answer. I like the idea of having a seperate library.

Answer (score 0):

Why not build stored procedures and have your query library use them?
As long as you have a defined set of parameters that you don't change, and read from named output fields not column ID's, you should be golden if you need to to tweak the SQL in the queries.