# Tidiest method for executing a large SQL query in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a SQL query that is around 50 lines long.

I'm wondering what would be the be the most maintainable and readable method for executing this, as it looks quite large. So far, I have thought of the following options:

- Create a stored procedure in the database
- SQL query is inline, in the method
- Store the query as a SQL file in the project and load when required (I'm also not sure if these should be compiled in or not).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best place to write SQL queries](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197852/best-place-to-write-sql-queries)

Comment: @JeffO: the title of that other question sounds clearly like a dupe, but neither the questions nor its answer mentions the possibility of storing things server-side.

Comment: There is one critical piece of information missing from your question. Is this an on-line query (e.g. something that happens in real time, part of normal application operation)? Is this a scheduled batch, happening as part of normal operation, but in a background thread? Or is it an on-demand batch, executed as needed by a person? I've added one of these options in the question, feel free to change accordingly!

Comment: @Sklivvz: IMHO changing or even narrowing the whole meaning of the question by an edit is not a good idea. Better give the OP to do this on his own. So sorry, I reverted your edit

Comment: @DocBrown fair enough. I find that such a change can be useful to clarify to the OP what the problem is and how it can be solved. They can certainly refer to the [revision history](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/338503/2) for that anyways.

Comment: @DocBrown I think that as a way to salvage closed question [aggressive edits](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2153/168) can be okay. For an open question edit like in rev 2 would be too risky indeed but at a closed one, why not. Especially given that asker can roll it back or replace with their own correction

Comment: @gnat: I found the question quite answerable the way it was.

Comment: [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601) @DocBrown (two other users who dropped garbage answers at it also found it answerable, that's not a good sign)

Comment: @DocBrown if any realistic answer must start with *"it depends..."*, then there's something wrong with the question. Good questions have clear answers :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz: in the topic of software engineering, 80% of all answers start (or at least could start) with "it depends", and the answers which don't are too often presenting a dogmatic point of view. But I agree, this question could have been written much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends heavily on how you manage your sources and your DB schema, the query itself and what it is used for, and the kind of evolvability and reusability you expect for the query.

Storing queries as views or stored procedures in the database is an option if the application which uses the query is versioned together with the DB schema, and deployment of a new version of the application is typically done together with a potential deployment of a new version of the views, stored procedures or other parts of the DB schema. For some application systems, especially for lightweight DB systems or systems where you have one DB exclusively used by your application system, this is fine, for others (for example, enterprise DB systems used by many different applications and/or users) this might cause additional administrative overhead you might want to avoid.

IMHO the most benefit for having the query stored in the database comes from the possibility of easier reusing it from different applications, and from the possibility of testing it easier in isolation. However, if that is your scenario, make sure you know the life cycle of the applications and the query: you may end up with different versions of application A, application B and query C, because when the query becomes a reusable component on its own, you need to manage dependencies between these different components.

The advantage of having the query inline is, you have the full logic of the query together with the tightly related code for taking the result **in one place**. Having the query part of the application makes it often easier to manage and deploy new versions. Especially when you query is not just parametrized, but dynamically created, this may be the only feasible option. However, you should be careful not to mix the query and further processing in one huge method. Furthermore, you should put such methods in a strictly defined place, for example, the db access layer of your application, and not, for example, in the UI layer.

Having the query as a separated SQL file on the client side might have some advantages in terms of readability, and it may be possible to reuse it from different applications inside the same application system (though you can get the latter also from an inline query stored in a reusable library). If this really brings benefits depends on the programming language and the possibilities to embed SQL queries directly in code - if the language/environment you are using provides such a mechanism, it may be the better alternative to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Longer queries are better to be stored on database server. That will save your data being transmitted and save you from SQL injection too.

Also such procedures are pre-compiled on the database server, so you save on that, too.

Comment: Stored procedures do not improve performance:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/414272/Stored-Procedures-DO-NOT-increase-performance

Comment: Nor do they provide better protection against injection than parameterised queries. It's weird how stubbornly these old myths persist.

Comment: I would like to understand why they will not provide better protection. IMO less the code being sent over the wire, less the risk. Isn't it that way? I am not saying 100% security from SQL injection, but safer than sending 50 lines query over the connection.

Comment: If my query is properly parameterised, I don't see what the security concern is. Could you explain?

Comment: SQL injection doesn't happen over the wire between your application and the database (which should be within your local network anyway). It happens when queries are built directly from user input text - a problem solved decades ago by parameterisation.

Comment: @AnandVaidya, please explain a little further why you think your answer is good. C# can prepare the queries precompiling them as needed, and I don't see any evidence about the data savings on transmission and the statement about SQL Injection is wrong, like the previous comments already addressed.

Comment: They are also not 'pre-compiled' on the database server....

Comment: I agree that I was wrong and agree with Doc Brown's answer! Thanks for correcting me.